# how to get top 10 products per each month

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

given a table with date, user_id, price, quantity, product_id, how to get the top10 (by means of quantity) product_id per month.
if this is per day, I think I can use `dense_rank() over(partition by date order by quantity`, but how to solve this which is by month?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: date is presumably a `date` datatype, so it has steps of a day. You want steps of a month, so partition by month and year.

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger! I should be better than this :)